Can Mermin-Wagner theorem apply to system with Anderson-Higgs mechanism?
Can the Mermin-Wagner theorem apply to the system with the Anderson-Higgs mechanism where the Goldstone mode is absent? A "physics" view to understand Mermin-Wagner theorem may be attributed to the thermal fluctuation coming from Goldstone, which leads to an integral in the form $\int\frac{d^Dk}{k^2}$ which diverges when $D\leqq2$ (see Condensed Matter Field Theory, A.Altland, B.D.Simons 8.1.1). However, when there is a gauge field, because of the Anderson-Higgs mechanism, the Goldstone mode is eaten by gauge field, so there is no gapless mode, thermal fluctuations may not destroy long-range order when $D\leqq2$. So is there 1d or 2d superconductors? if not, why? And is the above theory equivalent to the famous proof using Bogolyubov inequality, I have read the article  https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.158.383, but I am not good at math and get lost in these equations. So if there is a "physics" picture, it will help a lot.

There are two different cans of worms you are trying to open here.
First of all, the real life consideration: 2D and 1D materials still couple to  gauge field in 3D.  So the gauge field lives mostly in the vacuum and is basically unscreened.  There is very little charged stuff to stir up the photons to begin with, and then the few photons there are just escape to infinity.  In fact, I think we routinely ignore gauge field dynamics when dealing with such low-dimensional systems, and it works pretty well.
And then there is a much deeper complication that most of us don't want to touch at all.  Ever heard of Elitzur's theorem?  The popular way to phrase it is "gauge symmetry cannot be spontaneously broken".  Or more precisely: "if a local operator $\phi(x)$ is not gauge invariant, one must have $\langle \phi(x) \rangle = 0$ under all circumstances."  So, yeah, technically speaking, you can't have a local order parameter, and the whole U(1) symmetry breaking thing doesn't even apply to superconductivity...
(Have a look at Hansson, Oganesyan and Sondhi if you are interested in detail.)
Granted, the instanton events that enforce Elitzur's are extremely rare.  Your superconductor must literally have an astronomical size before you see the long range order $\langle\phi(x)\rangle$ decays to zero.  Bottom line is, for most of us, the working description of superconductivity consists of

global U(1) symmetry breaking
gauge field is coupled semiclassically/perturbatively...
...and is basically not there for low-dimensional systems

It's a chimera, but it works exceedingly well.  If you take these ingredients, then you get hit by Mermin-Wagner below 3D.  If you don't, then have fun with all that topological order stuff, and Mermin-Wagner is the least of your concern.

Thank you very much! Your answer helps me a lot! I agree with you that when 2D and 1D materials couple to gauge field in 3D, although Anderson-Higgs happens, the resulting plasma frequency is too high, so it doesn't affect low-energy physics. However, as for Elitzur's theorem, when Anderson-Higgs happens, the gauge field already takes a gauge (under this very gauge, the degree of freedom of goldstone was absorbed in the gauge field). So when gauge is fixed, I think superconductivity long-range order $\langle c^\dagger c^\dagger\rangle$ can still be nonzero.
